# Procedurally constructing a building from an image

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, image-manipulation

I have a large data set of images.
These images contain buildings. I am looking for an intelligent way to extract data from these images.

### Input

- Collection of images of buildings with rough coordinates

---

### Method

- The program needs to be able to extract the image of the face of the building.
- Correct the image so it is "front facing" (some of the images are taken at angles to the face of the building)
- Assign tags to detail elements of the buildings face (windows, doors etc) and give these elements coordinates within the face of the building.
- Assign tags to textures of the building (ie Brick, concrete, misc 1, misc 2)
- Group similar building images together (using size and shape)
- Group similar detail elements and texture elements together into subdirectories of images.
- Assign coordinates (which are provided with source) to each building image

---

### Output

- a clean database of all building face imagery, with associated coordinates, textures, and detail elements with image coordinates, easily indexable via Javascript or PHP.

---

### Help

- I appreciate any and all advice on this project. Any links to useful code snippets/libraries/projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more likely that you'll get this done using Mechanical Turk than with a program

https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome

If so, your job would be to make a very simple to use GUI for a person to provide information you need to do the transformations and extractions.

1. Collect 4 points that are the corners of the front face
2. Extract that quadrilateral from the image
3. Use a quadrilateral warp to turn that into a rectangle
4. Show the user this image
5. Let them tag the parts
6. Let them fill in meta-data (Concrete, etc)
7. Assign a QA task to a different person that just checks it over (or alternatively, give the same task to a different person and QA if they disagree)